# What does the memcached return code 44120 mean?

Tags: ruby, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am getting a return code from my memcached cluster of value 44120, which is breaking my memcached-northscale ruby client because it does not know what this return code value means.

Can anyone shed light on what this code means and which ruby memcached clients are capable of handling it?

I am using an AWS ElastiCache cluster that is returning this value.

Thanks!

---

**Update**: I just tried to substitute memcached for memcached-northscale, and just got this exception:

```
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String

Where:
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/memcached-1.4.6/lib/memcached/memcached.rb, line 306
```

I don't know what the root is but my suspicion is that it's related to the earlier issue with memcached-northscale.

I also got an exception:

```
Memcached::Error: Unknown return code: 4832

Where:
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/memcached-1.4.6/lib/memcached/memcached.rb, line 631
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the default memcached timeout was being overridden with a very short timeout. Increasing the timeout removed these errors. I do not know why they were being caused by a short timeout however, it seems like a bug in the library someplace.